# Restoring a Vampire to mortal life

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-dark-ages, dark-ages-mage

I'm running a campaign in Dark Ages 2nd edition and I would like to know if there is any vampiric or mage power that can restore a vampire to mortal life.

My chronicle is set in Transylvania in the city of Prague. One of the players, a Brujah, hates their condition as a vampire and believes that if the Tremere were able to gain immortality through magical rituals then there must be a way to do the reverse to him.

The character doesn't want to be a vampire at Golconda, but a mortal instead.

Comment: A little off topic, but corresponding to your campaign: Prague is NOT in Transylvania.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Maybe.**

> Rumours speak of a sacred few who have escaped the Curse of Caine and
>   become mortal again. Such stories of Redemption have existed for
>   centuries, as have tales of eternal Damnation. If it seems outrageous that a vampire can permanently change his state of being through magical ritual, vampiric history offers many precedents.

e.g. Golconda, the Crimson Pool, the Tremere, Apotheosis and Amaranth.

### The Red Sign

There's actually an entire book that deals with this called *The Red Sign*, much like there is for everything else in oWoD, from which all the quotes are taken and naturally it's the Mages who would be the ones to accomplish such a feat. The method - the ritual of the Red Sign

> The Red Sign is at the heart of another legend of life and death. It is
>   the culminating movement of a communal ritual, one that can return the
>   undead to life. Like other legends of those who have overcome the
>   horrors of vampirism - whether by taking the Beast, walking in
>   sunlight for one blessed day, or simply escaping the madness and
>   persecution of vampiric society - such achievements are mythical,
>   unsubstantiated and ephemeral. No one has ever proven that the Red
>   Sign has been used to redeem the damned soul of a Vampire... but it is
>   only a matter of time.

There is a LOT of detail regarding the process of discovering the ritual, the tome that holds the knowledge of it, various tales and stories as well as possible ways of incorporating it into your own adventures. Rules-wise it is a difficulty 11 ritual requiring 10 successes as standard, although it is fundamentally up to the storyteller.

The book suggests that it might be easier (difficulty 11, but with a -3 mod available and only 5 successes) or even functionally impossible (30 successes or difficulty 15+) to succeed at the ritual depending on what direction the storyteller wishes to take. Maybe it changes over time as Gehenna approaches.

The ritual is such a major thing, after all, you are trying to break a curse laid down by the creator. The chronicle contained in the book is described as, among other things, *"world-shaking"* and an *"apocalypse plot"*.

> According to early legends, it is impossible to escape the Curse of
>   Caine. Other sources claim that such an event is inevitable, but
>   usually posit a prophecy that it heralds the ends of the world. When
>   the impossible becomes real, it is a sign that reality is unravelling,
>   and even more horrible events - such as the return of the
>   Antidiluvians to the world - might be equally possible.

So there you have it. I thoroughly recommend tracking down a copy of the book and giving it a read as it seems to answer your question nicely, but fundamentally if you are running the game then it is up to you.

> ... you're really creating your version of the world's inexorable
>   slide towards destruction.

Answer (score 1):

## There is a Way, for a Small Price

There is a way to make a vampire mortal again, and prevent repeated Embraces. Of course, you won't learn of these methods from the preachers of Golconda. But since you reject such an ethically rigid path, you should be a much more suitable candidate for the method.

The method bears the dramatic name of [Demonic Investment](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Demonic_Investment). Specifically the 'Rejuvenation' investment<sup>1</sup>. Yes, the specific investment was not as widely known even among the scholars of forbidden lore in the Dark Ages as it became in the nights before Gehenna, but surely it would be naïve to believe that there were no Infernalists in the Dark Ages<sup>2</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> Storytellers Handbook to the Sabbat, page 62: This Investment permanently transforms a vampiric Infenalist into a mortal. The Infernalist is immune to any further attempts to Embrace her and will most likely die if it is forced upon her. The Infenalist will now age normally.
<sup>2</sup> Vampire Dark Ages Companion, chapter 7 talks about Infernalism.

Comment: How does this cure vampirism?

Comment: @T.J.L. What do you mean? The very first sentence tells how it helps.

Comment: It says it does. It doesn't say *how*. Perhaps a quote from the reference would provide sufficient detail.

Comment: @T.J.L. It doesn't explain how the infernal power works, just that it transforms a vampiric Infernalist into a mortal one.

Comment: Great... quote it.

Answer (score 0):

How about combining Mind 5 with Life 4 and transfering the consciousness of the vampire into another body? M20 p.522.
But for that there would be needed already another body or the magus need life 5 to create one before.

Comment: This question is about Mage Dark Ages, not M20. They’re different editions of the game.

Answer (score -1):

You could probably break this up into two parts. First, escaping the curse of Vampirism. Even if the character is able to find a "cure" for the Vampire state, becoming a Vampire involves dying as a mortal. The best a character may be able to hope for would be to return to mortality as a corpse. Not necessarily the result your player is after. This is where the magic ritual could come in, to restore life to a dead body. Raiding a Mage chantry of the Hermetic Order, or the archives of the Tremere, might get you what your character is looking for there. I'd set this as the goal for an entire campaign, trying to pull together esoteric artefacts and ingredients to perform the ritual.

Comment: Welcome to RPG Stack Exchange! Please take the [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) when you've got a moment.

Comment: It's preferred that answers are objective and backed by official sources. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer offers a few useful details on how to make productive answers. And in time, welcome!